# pub/sub on daily table

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I am looking to implement pub/sub&Dataflow connection from my AppEngine to Bigquery 
as I am trying to understand how exactly to define it

my problem is that I have a daily table a new table on Bigquery that opens once a day,
When I try to set the dataflow it only gives me an option to choose one table

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to do? You want to build a pipeline from BigQuery or to BigQuery and save it in a new table every day? I need better understanding so I can further help you.

Comment: I am streaming around 1000 event records a second to bigquery today,to manage the service better I decided to stream the data using pub/sub and dataflow from the server means server -> pub/sub -> dataflow -> bigquery now the way that our big query is built today is that we open every day with a job a new table for example table20200409 for today now when you set up a new dataflow you need to define the table which will get the data , but our table change everyday and only the table prefix is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you said in the comment section, you could use [Daily Sharded tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables) or [Time/day Partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables).

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#template-tables), you can stream in both types.  However, I must point out some differences, you would have to consider.

**Time/Day Partitioned Tables:**

- These tables are internally divided into into segments/partitions, which are easier to manage and improve query performance. You can have more information about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#partitioning_versus_sharding).
- There are [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#partitioned_tables), such as maximum number of partitions per table, which you have to check if they attend your needs.
- When querying against Day/Time partitioned tables you can use the pseudo columns _PARTITIONTIME or _PARTITIONDATE, each one has its own format, which you can read more [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#querying_ingestion-time_partitioned_tables_using_pseudo_columns).
- You can stream individual rows using [***insertAll***](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaming_into_ingestion-time_partitioned_tables) requests.
- According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#dt_partition_shard), Partitioned tables perform better than sharded tables because you don't need a copy of the metadata and verify permissions for each table.

**Daily Sharded table:**

- There is not a pseudo column you can use to manage/query your database.
- There is not a limit for the amount of tables you can create, you can read more about the quotas [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs).
- You [create daily tables using templates](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#template-tables), such as ***`<targeted_table_name> + <templateSuffix>`***, all with the same schema.

If you choose Partition table, you could create a date partition table and stream into it. Although, if you prefer Sharded table, you can use a template to create tables.

In addition, I would encourage you to read more about the differences and characteristics of each of one [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#dt_compare).